# delete lines that match a pattern from a given line to the end of the file

Tags: ex-mode

If I have a file with a lot of comments in it and I want to delete all of the comments from say, line 3 to the end of the file, what's the best way to do it?

I'm stuck, since what I first tried doesn't seem to do quite what I want:

```
:3,$/^#/d
```

Instead of looking for the pattern and deleting lines with it in the range from 3 to the end of the file it deletes all of the lines from 3 to through a line that matches the pattern, and then stops.

So how do I apply an ex command to a range of lines.  In this case it's to to the end of a file, but would it be different if I were to do it to a mark, or between lines 10 and 20 or other ranges?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the [`:global`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_10.html#10.4) command for that:

```
:3,$g/^#/d
```

You can apply it to lines **not** matching a pattern:

```
:3,$g!/^#/d
```

You can use the full range mechanism with it (see `:help :range`):

```
:.,/#define/+3g/^#/d
```

And you can use it with any command:

```
:3,$g/^#/s/foo/bar/g
```

It's one of the most powerful commands in Vim, please see `:help :global` for details.

Comment: You could also use `:3,$v/foo/d` for lines that do not match a pattern. `:h vglobal`